# Missing form when including a php file

Tags: php, mysql

Why is that when i comment this code my form shows then,
[image]

After removing the double backslash from the include("c.php"); ,the form disappears

[image]

Here is the content of c.php

[image]

Comment: What's in c.php ? Maybe it's juste an html tag not properly closed or something.

Comment: There's a huge syntax error in c.php you probably wanted to write while($row = ...) { echo $row...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `include` files always on the top above `<body>` of the page

Comment: This is nonsense. Depends on the usage.

Comment: comment this
  error_reporting(0);
Then you will become able to see the errors regarding the include.

Answer (score -1):

Check if `c.php` doesn't provoke any fatal error. That would end the whole script, hence the form not showing anymore.

By removing `error_reporting(0)` you would also be capable of seeing that error ;-)